# I cannot turn off iCloud Keychain, please help

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id, keychain, two-factor-authentication

Apple's implementation of two-factor authentication is asking me to input my iPhone password on my Mac.

I feel that this is inappropriate, and I suspect that iCloud (which I have disabled) is attempting to enable iCloud Keychain when I have specifically NOT authorized this.

Compare this to when I login to apple.com. This sends me a one-time password to my device and I type it in. That is what I was expecting.

**So, how I do make this dialog go away without providing my iPhone password to my computer or my computer password to my iPhone?**

Also, I note that I can set reminders (synced to Apple) on my computer and retrieve them on my phone. So clearly my account sync is working. **What additional feature is the computer actually trying to set up with this dialog?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not Apple's [two-factor-authentication](/questions/tagged/two-factor-authentication) — this is iCloud [keychain](/questions/tagged/keychain). To sync your keychain, you need to enter the password for the device asked. Other iCloud functionality will continue to work, since you've already passed 2FA.

Comment: I have just double checked and NONE of my Apple devices have iCloud keychain enabled. Is there anything else I can do to triple check that this is disabled?

Comment: I do find it perverted that Apple tries so hard to collect my information, even if I read every word of every pop-up that they try to trick me with (i.e. every time the phone upgrades.)

Comment: Possibly related: I cannot disable beta software updates. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285986/i-cannot-turn-off-beta-software-updates?noredirect=1#comment360781_285986

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the title to show this is related to iCloud keychain.

Answer (score 1):

**Just type in your password and 6-digit authorization code.**

Why would Apple, the same company that [refused to unlock the iPhone that was used by a San Bernardino shooter for the FBI](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/national-security/us-wants-apple-to-help-unlock-iphone-used-by-san-bernardino-shooter/2016/02/16/69b903ee-d4d9-11e5-9823-02b905009f99_story.html?utm_term=.d83072d1d43c), care for your password. You are insignificant to them since you're account is only one of [500 million iCloud accounts](http://appleinsider.com/articles/13/06/04/apples-500m-user-accounts-second-only-to-facebook-viewed-as-key-driver-of-future-growth). In fact, that article showing the number of user accounts was from June 4, 2013; that's over 5 years ago.

---

[This help page has a section](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915#howitworks) that tells you how two-factor authentication works:

> With two-factor authentication, your account can only be accessed on devices you trust, like your iPhone, iPad, or Mac. When you want to sign in to a new device for the first time, you'll need to provide two pieces of information—your password and the six-digit verification code that's automatically displayed on your trusted devices. By entering the code, you're verifying that you trust the new device. For example, if you have an iPhone and are signing into your account for the first time on a newly purchased Mac, you'll be prompted to enter your password and the verification code that's automatically displayed on your iPhone.
>
> Because your password alone is no longer enough to access your account, two-factor authentication dramatically improves the security of your Apple ID and all the personal information you store with Apple.
>
> Once signed in, you won’t be asked for a verification code on that device again unless you sign out completely, erase the device, or need to change your password for security reasons. When you sign in on the web, you can choose to trust your browser, so you won’t be asked for a verification code the next time you sign in from that computer.

Once you verify, the popup will never show up again on that device unless you reinstalled the OS or something similar to that action. You could even change your iPhone's password if you were still fearing that Apple is going to hunt you down.

Comment: The documentation you quote states that "your password and the six-digit verification code that's automatically displayed on your trusted devices" are requested. That is NOT what I am asking about. Instead I am being asked to set up iCloud keychain without my authorization. I will update the title to reflect this since I was downvoted.