# I cannot turn off beta software updates

Tags: macos, beta-seed-program

Step one, open App Store control panel:
Step two, click CHANGE under beta updates:

[image]

Step three, click DO NOT SHOW BETA SOFTWARE:

[image]

Now if you look at the control panel it looks like this and the beta section is gone:

[image]

---

Here is where it gets weird. If you quit and then reopen the control panel it look like the first screen shot again.

So how do I actually STOP beta software updates?

Comment: "Can't ...due to a network problem" might be significant.

Comment: Possibly related: Apple has remotely enabled iCloud Keychain on my account without my permission. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285384/apple-id-settings-popup-asks-for-iphone-passcode-but-i-dont-want-to-give-it

Comment: Are you on a filtered network? I know some schools, for whatever reason, block some Apple services. This could be the cause of the problem